# How to highlight area in KML googlemaps on mouse-over event?

Tags: kml

How to highlight area in KML googlemaps on mouse-over event?

I am trying the same thing as [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14642/how-to-highlight-the-area-in-google-map-on-mouse-hover/30717#comment41021_30717)

I saw the example given with polylines on the same link above.
But is the same thing possible with KML. I have KML for various regions, But now what i need is to display them in the same way as shown in the wiki-link(wikimapia) or may be in this way - http://livelovely.com

According to what i have found out, the mouse-over event of a KML does not work as of now. So we have to find a way around to this, as in the example of polylines  mouse-over event of tables is used as well if we go through the source code of "lovely.com" they have used mouseover event on `div` tag, but i don't understand how.

Does any one know how this should be done? Any suggestions, highly appreciated.